In extended events, event sqlserver.sql_batch_completed, client_connection_id do not match sys.dm_exec_connections for the same session_id
My goal is the following. I want to get client_net_address for every query traced (the same of sys.dm_exec_connections for matching session_id). Extended events system do not provides this straight. I have a logon trigger that stores into a table every client_connection_id for every connection that is made (aside client_net_adress). Next, I made a trace of queries, from which I return client_connection_id. To my surprise, client_connection_id never match even on an still opened connections. In my example I do not try to join in the table feeded by the logon trigger. I simply go straight to sys.dm_exec_connections to see if there is a match. No match...
Before i create this event, i ensure that it isn't existing. I also drop any target file created from previous run.
CREATE EVENT SESSION AuditReq ON SERVER
ADD EVENT sqlserver.login(
    ACTION (sqlserver.client_connection_id, sqlserver.session_id, sqlserver.client_hostname)
),

  ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed
  (
    ACTION
    (    
      sqlserver.server_principal_name
    , sqlserver.sql_text
    , sqlserver.client_app_name
    , sqlserver.client_hostname
    , sqlserver.database_name
    , sqlserver.session_id
    , sqlserver.client_connection_id
    )
    WHERE [sqlserver].[is_system]=(0)
  )
ADD TARGET package0.asynchronous_file_target(
SET 
  filename = N'D:\_tmp\AuditReq.xel'
, max_file_size=(5)
, max_rollover_files=(5)
)
WITH 
  (
    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB
  , EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS
  , MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=5 SECONDS -- adjust
  , MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB
  , MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE
  , TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF
  , STARTUP_STATE=OFF
  );
GO
ALTER EVENT SESSION AuditReq ON SERVER STATE = START;
GO

I then generate some activity on the same connection in SSMS.
Declare @Start datetime = getdate()
drop table if exists #tmp
Select * into #tmp from sys.dm_exec_requests
While (1=1)
Begin
  truncate table #tmp
  If DATEDIFF (ss, @start, GETDATE())>5 Break
  Insert into #tmp select * from sys.dm_exec_requests
  waitfor delay '00:00:00.3'
End

When I query the extended events file with this query:
Select ev.*, Hc.client_net_address, Hc.connection_id
From 
  (
  SELECT 
      F.file_Name, F.file_Offset, F.event_data,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/@name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS event_name,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/data[@name="row_count"]/value)[1]', 'bigint') AS row_count,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]', 'int') AS [session_id],
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS sql_text,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="client_hostname"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS client_hostname,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="client_app_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS client_app_name,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS database_name,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="username"]/value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS username,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') AS event_time,
      xEvents.event_data.value('(event/action[@name="client_connection_id"]/value)[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS connection_id
        
  FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('D:\_tmp\AuditReq*.xel', NULL, null, null) as F --'D:\_tmp\QueryTrackingSession_0_133625926429210000.xel',   9111552) --null, null)
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS event_data) AS xEvents
  ) as ev
  LEFT JOIN master.sys.dm_exec_connections  as Hc
  On Hc.connection_id = ev.connection_id
order by ev.event_time desc;

I find the connection_id value never match the one of the existing session traced and left open. I tried many ways to work around this discrepancy. Directly querying sys.dm_exec_connections for current @@spid returns a different connection_id. I also checked the XML, the value isn't different.
SQL Server docs states clearly the client_connection_Id should match connection_id from sys.dm_exec_connections. Anyone understanding my problem?  Is it an anomaly in extended events data?
I'm running SQL2019 latest CU26.
